# If user logged in redirect to query sting entry

Tags: php

Im trying to redirect user to a query string link after login but am having issues. Heres what i have

```
if (is_user_logged_in() ) { 
wp_redirect ( echo $_GET['refer'] );
exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing echo inside the parentheses? Leave just the $_GET, also is there any errors displayed?

Comment: that worked. Thanks!!